# Django ArrayField Query issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

My model structure is as below -

```
class DataModel(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    last_updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    imp_id = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    members = ArrayField(models.TextField(null=True, blank=True))
```

The member data is stored in below format -

```
"{"{'Memberno': '1', 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Dow', 'education_type': '','FamilyMembers': []}"}"
```

How do I filter for first_name similar to 'John'?
My filter query that I tried was -

```
models.DataModel.objects.exclude(members__icontains='{}')
```

But this was for exclude. Can somebody please help me filter for first_name?

Comment: Try this one `models.DataModel.objects.exclude(members__icontains=None)`

Comment: @AshishSondagar But I want to filter when first_name is like 'jon'

Comment: then use this kind of ORM query `models.DataModel.objects.filter(first_name='jhon')`

Comment: I want to filter first_name from members ArrayField

Comment: do you want to return just the first_name?

Comment: @Sher Yes first_name.

Comment: why not use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) instead?